# Override method for Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am customizing my Active admin with below code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
  index do
    Question.column_names.each do |c|
      column c.to_sym
    end
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      Question.column_names.each do |c|
        row c.to_sym
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, I don't want to show some fields like `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. How can I override this method to hide those fields? Is there a way to apply for all other model also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the file `app/models/application_record.rb`. Here I write a new method ( u can override current one if u want, but I think new method this one is better )

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.column_names_without(*names)
    column_names - (%w[created_at updated_at] | names)
  end
end
```

Then, the `ActiveAdmin` code is modified to

```
ActiveAdmin.register Question do
  index do
    selectable_column
    Question.column_names_without('quiz_id').each do |c|
      column c.to_sym
    end
  end

  show do
    attributes_table do
      Question.column_names_without('quiz_id').each do |c|
        row c.to_sym
      end
    end
  end

end
```